# Update plot in a loop in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am making multiple plots on the same canvas using data from dataframe. I want to update the plot in a loop based on newly filtered data.

The code I am using is:

```
from IPython import display

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,13))



ax.set_xlim(-0.5,2.5)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5,3.5)

# d_a is a list of dataframes created using different filters
for data_filtered in d_a:
    
    for index,row in data_filtered.iterrows():
        x_values = [row['x'] - xy_offset[row['direction']][0]/2.1,
                    row['x']+xy_offset[row['direction']][0]/2.1]
        y_values = [row['y']-xy_offset[row['direction']][1]/2.1,
                    row['y']+xy_offset[row['direction']][1]/2.1]
       
 # for each row in the dataframe a plot is drawn
        plt.plot(x_values,y_values, linewidth=20,color= 'green',
                    alpha = 0.1


               )
    t.sleep(0.5)    

    display.display(plt.gcf())

    display.clear_output(wait =True)
```

Output:(Dynamic and changes with the iteration)
[image]

Now the idea is to use a varying value of 'alpha' in the plot based on a certain value in the row of the dataframe.
When I plot this, the opacity just keeps on increasing even when alpha is kept constant as in the code snipped shown.

Shouldn't the display be cleared entirely and a new plot made instead?

Comment: *1) Now the idea is to use a varying value of 'alpha' in the plot based on a certain value in the row of the dataframe.*
Is `alpha` a function of x and y? In this case you may use heatmap.
*2) the opacity just keeps on increasing even when alpha is kept constant*.
Seems like one plot is overlayed by another, that's why green lines become darker.

Comment: alpha is a function of another column that varies between 0-100. It does seem the plots are overlayed, but shouldn't it be cleared every time since I'm clearing all outputs?

Comment: I would say you are clearing the ipython display but not the matplotlib figure, have you tried with `plt.gcf().clf()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear either the matplotlib axis or figure also, with `plt.cla()` or `plt.clf()` respectively. Otherwise the lines will be drawn onto the same matplotlib axis object in memory, and redrawn at each iteration.

```py
from IPython import display
import numpy as np
import time as t

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,13))
ax = fig.subplots()
shifts = [1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2]
for shift in shifts:
    ax.plot([0, 1], [0 + shift/10, 1 - shift/10], linewidth=20, color= 'green', alpha = 0.1)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    t.sleep(0.5)
    plt.cla()
    display.clear_output(wait =True)
```